# How to apply phi-functions to matrices?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I am implementing an explicit numerical integration technique, based on readings from Hochbruck and Ostermann (2010). They use the following formulation:

[Excerpt from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqcIh.png)

Here, the matrix A is a linear estimation of the Jacobian of the differential equation system, and g is the leftover nonlinear terms. It calls for the usage of a phi function, defined:

$$\phi_{1}(z)=\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}.$$

But it says to apply this to a square matrix? I understand the matrix exponential, but how do you divide by a square matrix? Should I multiply by the matrix inverse or divide term-by-term? Or is there another meaning?

Comment: Rather than implementing this yourself, take a look at [ExpoKit](https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/) for efficient Fortran/Matlab code. It has since been ported to a number of other languages, [e.g. Julia](https://github.com/acroy/Expokit.jl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These helper functions are defined to avoid the matrix inverse. Thus the function $\phi_1$ can also be applied to singular matrices. Insert the power series of the matrix exponential to find
$$
\phi_1(A)=I+\tfrac12A+\tfrac16A^2+...+\tfrac1{n!}A^{n-1}+...
$$
For efficient evaluation you would use the eigen-decomposition $A=U^{-1}JU$ and then compute
$$
\phi_1(A)=U^{-1}\phi_1(J)U,
$$
where the middle splits according to the Jordan blocks of $J$ and the usual rules for the evaluation of matrix functions on Jordan blocks apply.

More elaborate tricks to reduce floating-point errors and/or computation costs exist.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation! I have a few quick follow-up questions if you have time:

1) Is there a general name for these phi-functions? Are there existing functions in matlab that make estimates of phi1?

2) Just to be clear, the best I could do to program such a function would be to estimate it using power series?

Comment: 1) I'm not aware of a name, could be helper or auxiliary functions, or exponential remainder functions, they routinely occur in Rosenbrock and exponential Runge-Kutta methods, there should be some slang for it. 2) Using the power series is inefficient but simple to implement, there should be readily available sources for the evaluation of analytical functions as matrix functions.

Comment: @Moo Take a look at `funm` Matlab function and the references there https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/funm.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the action of matrix phi-functions to a vector,
then you can also consider to compute the exponential of an extended matrix as shown in Theorem 1 in the paper [Expokit: A Software Package for Computing, Sidje R., ACM Trans. Math. Softw., 24(1):130-156, 1998] and others.

The following Matlab code computes $\varphi_p(tA)c\in\mathbb{C}^n$, i.e., the $p$-th phi-function of $tA\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ applied to a $c\in\mathbb{C}^n$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a possible time step, by evaluating the matrix exponential of an extended matrix $X\in\mathbb{C}^{n+p\times n+p}$:

```
X = A;
X(1:n,n+1) = c;
X(n+1:n+p-1,n+2:n+p)=eye(p-1);  
X(n+p,n+p)=0;
expX=expm(dt*X);
phipAc=expX(1:n,end)*dt^(-p); % = phi_p(t*A)*c
```

For $p=1$, a small choice of $n$, and a diagonalizable matrix $A$ with nonzero eigenvalues you can compute a reference solution using the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ as following

```
[Q,lam] = eig(A,'vector');
philam = expm1(dt*lam)./(dt*lam);
phipAc_ref = Q*diag(philam)*inv(Q)*c;
```

(here the auxiliary $\texttt{expm1}$ computes the exponential minus 1 of the given vector and does improve the accuracy when eigenvalues of $A$ are close to zero.)

For further works on the computation of matrix phi-functions for applications in exponential integrators you can also have a look at [Computing the Action of the Matrix Exponential, with an Application to Exponential Integrators, Higham and Al-Mohy, 2011.] or [Algorithm 919: A Krylov Subspace Algorithm for evaluating the $\phi$-Functions Appearing in Exponential Integrators, Niesen and Wright, 2012.]